Programmatically open keyboard in React?
I need to create a custom (fake) text input element (colorized words/letters, borders around words etc) which has to work on both desktop and mobile, but I can't find a way to open IOS/Android keyboard programmatically when user clicks on the fake input.
All searches lead to react-native which is not what I want. Is it okay to create a hidden input field and focus it on click? Would it affect user experience (e.g. automatically scroll to the hidden input, accessibility when focusing using Tab)? What is the proper way of doing this?

Have you tried the fake input thing to see if it would work?

Focusing an input that's styled to not be visible is certainly worth testing.  Accessibility may be a concern, if that's a concern for your needs at all.  But if it's part of the page and in the location you need it and is only hidden because another element is obscuring it (that is, not using display:none or visibility:hidden or anything that actively hides the element itself), theoretically that could work and is certainly worth trying.

As an alternative idea... Perhaps you could make use of a content-editable div, which allows the user to focus it for input but also gives you styling control.  You may be able to respond to the input events and replace the actual input with your own output.
